# How can I resolve min SDK version error in flutter for android development?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a bluetooth app using flutter in android studio. I am getting the following error:
The plugin `flutter_blue` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G885F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Apps\Bluetooth\android\app\build.gradle' line: 51
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile build file 'C:\Apps\Bluetooth\android\app\build.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> build file 'C:\Apps\Bluetooth\android\app\build.gradle': 51: Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
> In case you tried to configure a property named 'minSdkVersion', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
> @ line 51, column 24.
> minSdkVersion: 19
> ^

1 error

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you show me file "C:\Apps\Bluetooth\android\app\build.gradle". Replace "minSdkVersion: 19" with "minSdkVersion 19"

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i solved it by changing the minSDK 19 to 29, just update the number from 19 to 29 and try build your app.